# Is it safe to Alter an existing stored procedure to use output parameters?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, output-parameter

**Can changing an existing parameter of a stored procedure to an output parameter have any impact on existing code?**

For context, I have stored procedure which accepts and then modifies an parameter, returning the modified parameter by selecting it.  C# Callers receive the returned parameter via `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`.

The stored procedure looks something like this:

```
CREATE procedure UpsertData
    @objectid int, --This line would change
    ...
as

if not exists (select objectid from mytable where objectid = @objectid)
begin
    insert into mytable (...) values (...)
    set @objectid = (select scope_identity() as int)
end
else
begin
    update mytable
    set ...
    where objectid=@objectid
end
select @objectid
```

I now intend to call this stored procedure within other stored procedures. Using [INSERT-EXEC](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC) would allow me to avoid modifying `UpsertData`, which is used in several places.

However, it strikes me as cleaner to replace `@objectid int,` with `@objectid int output,`.  I am unsure if this is safe; the stored procedure is called in many places, so I fear it might break in some unanticipated fashion.  **Is this a legitimate concern?**

Comment: Yes, it is. Any code that use this procedure would have to change.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Please give an example of code that would behave differently after making this change. I tried running existing code that talks to such a stored procedure and it worked whether the parameter was an output parameter or not.

Comment: You mean to keep the select as well as changing the parameter to output?

Comment: Then I think it's safe. I thought you are going to change the stored procedure and remove the select... AFAIK, sql server output parameters are actualy input/output.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: You are correct.  I did sanity check that this change doesn't break anything obvious, but there's still the possibility that it breaks something subtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems safe.

From
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx :

> You can execute a stored procedure with OUTPUT parameters and not
>   specify OUTPUT when executing the stored procedure. No error is
>   returned, but you cannot use the output value in the calling program.